# Who is מהרי''א?

Tags: acronyms, malbim

Meir Leibush ben Yehiel Michel Wisser constantly refers to מהרי''א? What is his full name?

For example ([Malbim on Shmuel II 22:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Malbim_on_II_Samuel.22.1?lang=bi)):

> אך למה הוצג גם כאן, ולמה באו פה שנויים רבים וחלופים בתיבות ובאותיות, צריכים אנו לשמוע לדברי מהרי"א, חבר השירה הזאת בבחרותו בהיותו בתוך צרותיו, ועשאה כוללת לכל הצרות...

Comment: https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%99%22%D7%90

Comment: מורינו הרב יצחק אברבנאל

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this article](https://www.etzion.org.il/he/tanakh/studies-tanakh/biblical-commentaries/malbims-commentary), it's Isaac Abarbanel:

> "אברבנאל זכה להערכה רבה מאת מלבי"ם, אשר כינהו "אביר המפרשים השר מהרי"א

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the other answers, in the Malbim (and many commentaries on Tanach) it refers to [Yitzchak Abarbanel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Abarbanel).

In halachic works after his time, it refers to Yisroel Isserlein, the author of the Trumat HaDeshen. You'll see it often in the commentaries on the Tur and Shulchan Aruch.

As @Dov mentioned in a comment, [there are actually several different Rabbis referred to by that acronym](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%99%22%D7%90).